# Why does the address of pointer changes while passing?

Tags: c++, pointers

while implementing the BST by my own using struct, I got confused on how the pointer works.

here’s my simple code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
void ptr_change(int* p){
    cout<<&p<<endl;
    /*
     *address changes. why ? */
    return ;
}
int main(){
    //4. Pointer address integrity
    cout<<"4. Pointer address integrity"<<endl;
    int* p1;
    cout<<&p1<<endl;
    ptr_change(p1);
}
```

Why does the address changes when after passing it to the function as parameter??
Thank U!

Comment: Please copy and paste your code from the editor, and use the formatting tools to format it properly; don't show a screenshot. By providing text, others can copy parts of it to make reference/citations, and make edits to fix the problem.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau 
Sorry didn’t know this rule at all. 
Thank u for noticing me Remy and Karl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The address didn't change.  You're looking at two separate variables.

In the `main` function, you define a variable called `p1`.  This variable has a particular address.  You then pass the **value** of `p1` to the function `ptr_change`.

In `ptr_change`, it has a parameter called `p`.  This variable has its own address separate from `p1` in `main`, although it contains the same value as `p1`.

You may be confused because the parameter in question is a pointer.  It's no different than a non-pointer parameter.  For example:

```
void foo(int x)
{
    cout << &x << end;
}

int main()
{
    int y = 0;
    cout << &y << end;
    foo(y);
    return 0;
}
```

Here, `x` in `foo` and `y` in `main` are different variables each with their own address, but they both contain the value 0.

Comment: Thank you so much! The fact that the pointer contains the address confuses me :)

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a copy of the pointer to the function. It's like when you pass a -say- int variable, you pass a copy of it's value. When you pass a pointer to int, you are copying the pointer itself, which also points to the same memory location, but pointer itself can be stored at another random location.